# Updating a Pandas Dataframe with continuously streamed data

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

Complete beginner question:
I am trying to build a function which updated a Dataframe every n Minutes. However I am running into the problem that I am only able to get the last datapoint without properly being able to build a Dataframe of all data streamed over time.

I am using following function to download the base data (data interval-1):

```
data = Ticker.history(start=START_DATE_1, end=END_DATE_1, interval="5Min")
data = pd.DataFrame(Stock_historical.tail(LOADDATAFRAME))
data
```

This outputs the Dataframe:

```
   2022-10-13 14:40:00  0.96593 0.96597 0.96563 0.96581
```

Then I am trying to use this function to get the data of current timestep ( for testing purposes I am getting the data in 5 min Interval

```
def get_new_data():

    last_data_2 = Ticker.history(start=START_DATE, end=END_DATE, interval="5Min")

    last_data_2 = pd.DataFrame(Stock_historical.tail(LOADDATAFRAME))
    
    data_combined = pd.concat([data, last_data_2], axis = 0)
    
    return data_combined
```

Now when I call this code I get the concacted DF

```
data = get_new_data()
```

with output:

```
2022-10-13 14:40:00 0.96593 0.96597 0.96563 0.96581
2022-10-13 14:45:00 0.96580 0.96611 0.96574 0.96606
```

So far so good However the problem arises when I try to call this function again
instead of now returning a Dataframe with 3 row I only get the first and last one:

```
2022-10-13 14:40:00 0.96593 0.96597 0.96563 0.96581
2022-10-13 14:50:00 0.96550 0.96587 0.96533 0.96585
```

How do I fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

only get the tick history once, then repeatedly append to this with get_new_data():

```
import time
def get_new_data(data):

    last_data_2 = pd.DataFrame(Stock_historical.tail(LOADDATAFRAME))
    
    data_combined = pd.concat([data, last_data_2], axis = 0)
    
    return data_combined

data = Ticker.history(start=START_DATE, end=END_DATE, interval="5Min")
while (True):
     data = get_new_data(data)
     time.sleep(300)
```